# Error while using readOGR to import shapefiles

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using a Mac System and unable to read shape file.

```
states12 <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer= "cb_2018_us_state_500k", verbose=TRUE)
```

**The Error I am getting**
RStudio is Quitting from lines 30-43

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
Calls: <Anonymous> ... readOGR -> suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> ogrInfo
```

In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'rjson' was built under R version 4.0.5
2: package 'leaflet' was built under R version 4.0.5
3: package 'raster' was built under R version 4.0.5
Execution halted

Comment: Please tell the community what version of R/RStudio and specific packages are being used.

Comment: Try `dsn` with absolute path instead of relative, I remember myself getting the same error back in the day but I'm not 100% sure. Now I'm use `sf` for vector operations, simpler and faster. You can convert to `sp` objects if you need to use an specific function

Comment: Rstudio version - 2022.02.3 Build 492
Package used - library(rgdal)

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thanks for the response. I used the absolute path and still getting "Cannot open layer"

Comment: Did you tried with `layer= "cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp"`?

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well. Still have the same error.

Comment: Can you convince us you have the right location and name by editing your question and showing the output of `list.files(".")`? And also `file.exists("cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp")` which should be `TRUE`?